# Error on publishing workflow with custom activity

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, custom, workflow-activity

I have created a custom action using visual studio for SharePoint 2013. I have done this multiple times following instructions from various blogs and every time I get the below mentioned error.

```
(0, 10) The type or namespace name 'CrossSubsSiteAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))
(24, 16) The type or namespace name 'CrossSubsSiteAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))
```

I have added `safecontrol` entry. I have also added `authorizedType` entries both inside and outside `targetfx`.

These entries are added in web.config placed in 15 hive as well as inetpub under port of my web application. I am stuck on it for days and just cant figure out what is to be done.